# C# htmlagilitypack XPath Help

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have this xpath expression that does not work

```
"//div[child[0]::h4[text()[contains(.,'Dir')]]]/a"
```

To parse this html:

```
<div class="txt"> 
      <h4 class="c1"> 
        Dir
      </h4> 
    <a  href="/name/myname/">Bob</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to get at the link node (a). There are other html tags in the document with the same div/h4 hierarchy, with the only difference being the innertext of the h4 tag. So how do I check that the div class (1) has a sub h4 node with inner text "dir" AND (2) get the first link node (a). Do not assume the link is the next sibling of h4.

Comment: You were very close, except that you can't put a predicate on an axis, so `child[0]::` is incorrect. If you wanted the first `h4` child of `div`, you could use `//div[child::h4[1][text()[...]]/a`, or just `//div[h4[1][text()[...]]/a` since `child::` is implicit for elements. If the `h4` must be the first element child, then `//div[*[1]/self::h4[...]]/a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just use this xpath?

```
"//div[h4[contains(text(),'Dir')]]/a"
```

`child[0]` is not a valid axis AFAIK so it fails.

I don't know if this alone would satisfy your conditions without seeing a more complete example HTML.  But this certainly works for this one.

If it's possible that there are multiple `h4` elements within the `div` and you only want to check the first:

```
"//div[h4[1][contains(text(),'Dir')]]/a"
```

Comment: Note: I've made the assumption that you will be using the `SelectSingleNode()` method with these xpaths.  So if there are multiple `a` elements, this will already take the first of them (as required).

Answer (score 1):

> **How do I check that the div class (1) has a sub h4 node with inner text "dir" AND (2) get the first link node (a)**

use:

```
"//div[@class='txt' and h4[contains(.,'Dir')]]/a[1]"
```

Comment: Agree, except you probably don't need the `[1]` after `h4`. Or are you inferring that from the OP's `child[0]::h4`?

Comment: @LarsH your observation is _logically_ coherent. `h4` is enough as we are using it as conditional. OP asked for _a sub h4_ not the first.